# Visualize Large graph with Neo4j and GraphStream

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm, graph-visualization, graphstream

I would like to know if it is possible to operate on a very large graph dataset (300,000 nodes and 1.5 million edges) in neo4j using graphstream and vizualize it at the same time in browser as the graphstream operates on it ( I wish to run some community detection algorithms ).

Comment: I'm not familiar with GraphStream so I can't comment on that project, but Neo4j can easily handle that size graph. More info [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/capabilities-capacity.html#capabilities-data-size)

Comment: is real time visualization possible as I edit the graph in neo4j with the java connectors?

Comment: @adsun I'm also curious of how that is possible, did you find an answer?

Comment: @JeroenSteen Sorry i could not find a way to do it with the limited time i had, I moved on with a different idea to visualize community detection algorithms without using Neo4j.

Comment: @adsun, which different idea? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: @adsun Hello, I tracked your previous post on how you were making a interactive web application with GraphStream. I just wanted to find out how did that project go because I am thinking about making something similar.